# Missing template user_mailer/abc with "mailer". Searched in: * "user_mailer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

In app/mailers/ I have user_mailer.rb , defined as

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def abc
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail    to: "engr.imrannaqvi@gmail.com" ,
            subject: "Question Reporting"
  end
end
```

application_helper.rb defined as

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

and views/mailer/ cantain abc.html.erb defined as

```
<p>Hi Imran Haider,</p>
It's from the content
```

When i call it from controller using

```
  def report_spam
    UserMailer.abc().deliver    
    render json: {msg: 'success'}
 end
```

It throws me error

> Missing template user_mailer/abc with "mailer". Searched in: *
>   "user_mailer"

I don't know where i'm wrong

Comment: Put your **erb** file from **views/mailer/** to **views/user_mailer/**

Comment: @Abhi but error i mentioned clearly states that it's looking into mailer folder

Comment: It says it's searching in `user_mailer` not `mailer`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but i think my `application_mailer.rb` was not working fine . I removed `application_mailer.rb` and moved the `user_mailer` folder out of the `mailer` folder in `views` and it worked (#Abhe comment, below the question was the most helpful thing)